# Another word for "basic understanding"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a proposal and I require a substitute for the words "basic understanding" as I have already used it.
The sentence is:

> "Students who attend this lesson should walk away with ________________ (a basic
>   understanding) of...".

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ... thorough grounding in ...?

Comment: *...the **basics** of...?*

Comment: "The fundamentals of X."

Comment: Knowledge of, or a grasp of...

Answer (score 1):

***Acquaintance/familiarity*** may work.

> "Students who attend this lesson should walk away with *(basic)
>   **acquaintance/familiarity*** with ...".
>   "Students who attend this lesson should walk away 
>   ***acquainted/familiarized*** with ...".

M-W:

> **[acquaintance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquaintance)**
>   *noun*
>   **1b** :  personal knowledge :  familiarity : had no acquaintance with the facts of the case
>
> While he has some acquaintance with the subject, he is not an expert.
>
> **[familiarize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/familiarization)**
>   *verb*
>   **2**:  to make well acquainted : familiarize students with good literature